# How can I install Canon Pixma MG 3150?

Tags: drivers, 10.04, printing, canon, pixma

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 on a Toshiba Satellite and have today purchased a [Canon PIXMA MG 3150 printer](http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/canon-pixma-mg3150-wireless-all-in-one-inkjet-printer-15604270-pdt.html).

Ubuntu can't find the drivers online and the CD I have is "obviously" for ... you guessed it Windows.

I've taken the printer out of the box, plugged it all in as recommended, the laptop sees the new device but the device is not listed, I tried to open a similar printer from the list (canon PIXMA 3100 series) it tells me it is printing the test page but nothing happens on the printers end. do I need to do anything else?

Can someone give me some pointers were as to find the solution please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What makes you believe it doesn't work out of the box? Does it not list it after plugging in? Are the documents not printed correctly?

Comment: Hi gertvdijk, I've taken the printer out of the box, plugged it all in as recommended, the laptop sees the new device but it is not listed, I tried to open a similar printer from the list (canon PIXMA 3100 series) it tells me it is printing the test page but nothing happens on the printers end. do I need to do anything else? (sorry I'm new to Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Openprinting has a site to the [PIXMA MX350](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-PIXMA_MX350). According to this site the driver for your printer works perfect. So you can follow the official Ubuntu help about [setting up a printer](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/printing-setup.html):

1. Open the printer menu from system settings
2. Choose 'add' a new printer
3. Choose the correct printer model
4. give your printer a name
5. print a test document

Comment: Is XM 350 the same as MG 1350?

Comment: @FrankFerreira No, but qbi also edited your question erroneously. He changed the type of your printer. This should be reverted. (like you now did! :) )

Comment: Sorry, first time on this site, still getting to grips with the system, I'll get there ;)

Comment: @FrankFerreira Yeah, don't worry. I've pinged qbi on chat about his error. I did voted your question to be closed for the exact duplicate. It's the same question. Did you get somewhere using that question?

Comment: @gertvdijk Thank you for your help, I've followed the link posted ""There's also this question which is an exact duplicate: How do I get a Canon Pixma MG 3150 working?"", and just got my first page off of the new printer. Thank you ever so much ;)

Comment: @FrankFerreira Good. Then make sure to unaccept this answer to avoid confusion for other visitors bumping into this question with an accepted answer not working.